# C# code won't launch programs. Win32Exception was unhandled

Tags: c#, process

I'm making a program that launches a program when a button is clicked. It seems to work for programs such as Chrome or Word but not smaller programs such as fraps and gives me the error

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' occurred in System.dll Additional information: The system cannot find the file specified

```
private void Fraps_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.FileName = "fraps.exe";
    Process.Start(startInfo);
}
```

Comment: What is the actual message of the exception? I bet it has something to do with "I don't know where 'fraps.exe' is".

Comment: what is the thrown exception :) ?? can you put it here

Comment: is the exception "The system cannot find the file specified" ??

Comment: it seems it cant find the file here is the full message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' occurred in System.dll

Additional information: The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: you don't have the fraps.exe app in the debug directory of your project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.filename(v=vs.110).aspx):

> You must set at least the FileName property before you start the process. The file name is any application or document. A document is defined to be any file type that has an open or default action associated with it. You can view registered file types and their associated applications for your computer by using the Folder Options dialog box, which is available through the operating system. The Advanced button leads to a dialog box that shows whether there is an open action associated with a specific registered file type.

In your case fraps.exe is not a registered file type associated application. So give FULL PATH to fraps.exe

The Code Example would be like the following (Find fraps installation on your hdd and replace path to fraps.exe in second line)

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\fraps\fraps.exe"; // Your absolute PATH 
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Comment: Ahh I see that works, but is there a way so that if fraps.exe is in a different directory it would detect where it is so if it was installed somewhere else the application would still work?

Comment: you will need to set PATH I guess :)

Comment: It has nothing to do with having a file type registered, and everything to do with not being in the PATH environment variable/current directory; you should probably update the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

Windows does not know what "fraps.exe" is, and it can't find such an executable file in the folders it is told to search in.

Let's verify this. Open a command prompt and type in "fraps.exe". It should not matter where your current directory is; the home folder should do nicely.

[image]

As long as you have not installed fraps to your home folder, this is what you should see. Now, why would this work for "chrome.exe" (presumably, not the case on my system) but not fraps?

Behind the scenes, Windows is told to look in a number of folders when you type commands. You can see the full listing if you type in `SET` into the prompt, and search for `PATH`.

[image]

That's a bit of a mess, but it's where Windows is going to look for the program you want *after* looking in the current directory.

In this case, Windows can't find "fraps.exe" in the current directory (your `bin\Debug` folder) or any of the folders in PATH. So it throws its hands up and says `The system cannot find the file specified`.

You have two options to fix this:

One: **use the full path name.** If you know where fraps is installed, you can use the full path name of the executable instead, such as:

```
startInfo.FileName = @"c:\Program Files\Fraps\fraps.exe";
```

Two: **add the fraps install folder to the PATH environment variable**. This more tricky and complicated, but you more or less append the path that fraps in installed to into the PATH variable. You can either do this, or rely on the end-user to do this (though that does not sound like a good idea to me).

Both options require that you know *where* fraps is installed to, so it's a good idea to hardcode the value (if this program is only for yourself) or ask the user for the install path when starting/installing the program.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation that clears some things up the full path works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Was having the same problem from `Process.Start()`. I had an EXE whos solution platform was targeting "Any CPU".
My app was installed on a 64 bit CPU running EXCEL (also 64 bit).

The solution was to target an x64 build. (A.Kadir Bener eluded to this)

To change the `Solution Platform`
Right Click the solution in `Solution Explorer`...scroll down to `Configuration Manager...`
Under `Active solution platform:` select **x64** (if an option)
If x64 is not an option then select **New...**
Under `Type or select the new platform`...select **x64**

Answer (score 1):

If the exe which you will call is 32bit then your code must be 32bit also.
AnyCpu or 64bit gives that error.

Comment: This helped me.

Comment: Yes...make the app platforms (x86,x64) match.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, you can call any program that has a path entry in environment. Here, we are not sure if the exe exists in the bin directory of the executing application. Could you have tried with the full path, you would not have got the exception

I would suggest that you can bootstrap the exe as part of your app, since its not part of windows or you could hint the user to make sure path is in environment variables.

Comment: Sorry I'm not very good with visual studio how would I bootstrap the exe to my code?