# Exception thrown when trying to open a PowerPoint file with C#

Tags: c#, powerpoint

I am working on my first C# application. I am trying to open a PowerPoint file in fullscreen mode. The code requires cmd arguments. I placed my powerpoint `test.pptm` in the same folder as the output (debug and release) for my application. I have written the following code:

```
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        startInfo.FileName = "powerpnt.exe";
        startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        startInfo.Arguments = "/s test.pptm";

        try
        {
            using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
            {
                exeProcess.WaitForExit();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }
```

The code compiles, but when I try to run this code via a button, the console states:

`Exception thrown: 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' in System.dll`

I've tried to directly reference the pptm file by changing the following line:

`startInfo.Arguments = "/s c:\path\to\full\file\test.pptm";`

I get an error stating `Unrecognized escape sequence`. Has anyone experienced this before? I've been stuck on this for a little while. Thanks!

Comment: can you try this for me please? `startInfo.Arguments = "/s ""c:\path\to\full\file\test.pptm""";`

Comment: @PauloLima Thanks, that let's me put the full path. But the main problem still persists, that is `Exception thrown: 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' in System.dll`. The program seems to have the proper command needed, but it can't execute it.

Comment: see if [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27596215/c-sharp-code-wont-launch-programs-win32exception-was-unhandled) can help you

Comment: @PauloLima That solution worked for me. Another solution (one of the answers in this post) also did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prefix your file path with the @ sign

```
startInfo.Arguments = @"/s c:\path\to\full\file\test.pptm";
```

From MSDN

> A verbatim string literal consists of an @ character followed by a double-quote character, zero or more characters, and a closing double-quote character. A simple example is @"hello". In a verbatim string literal, the characters between the delimiters are interpreted verbatim, the only exception being a quote-escape-sequence.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx

A few pointers regarding your code to get it working

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;            
startInfo.FileName = "powerpnt.exe";
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.Arguments = @"/s ""fullpath with spaces in file names""";
```

1. Notice the escaped double quotes before and after the fullpath. This is to accommodate spaces in your file names or directories
2. Remove the line startInfo.UseShellExecute = false

Comment: @cubrr Noted. Put in the explanation too

Comment: Thanks a lot! It seems to be working now. The issue was the `startInfo.UseShellExecute = false` line. That cause my exception error.